# Check whether there exist at least one b for every a where each b has a foreign key reference to a

Tags: postgresql

Say that you have a table of `a`'s and a table of `b`'s where each b has a foreign key reference to the table of `a`'s. How would you write a SQL statement answering the question whether or not there exists atleast one b for every a?

To reify: Say that you have a table of users:

```
create table users (
  id           bigserial  primary key,
  name         text
);
```

and a table of hats that these users wear:

```
create table hats (
  id           bigserial  primary key,
  user_id      bigserial  references users,
  description  text
);
```

How would you write a query answering whether or not each user has at least one hat, or to rephrase: Is there any user without a hat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RhodiumToad on #postgresql@freenode answered:

Do you want a result like `(user_id, has_hat)`? Or just a list of users with hats, or users without hats? Or a single true/false result for "does any user not have a hat?"

The most efficient answer of the various different queries will be that to the first question:

```
select exists(
  select 1
    from users u
    where not exists(
      select 1
        from hats h
        where h.user_id=u.id));
```

This because it's (a) plannable as an anti-join and (b) stops on first match. There's also the added benefit of it literally saying "does a user exist such that no hat exists for that user" so it should be easy to understand for future readers.

The next best if you want more detail is the middle option (users with/without hats) like so:
    -- shows all users with at least one hat
    select *
    from users u
    where exists(
      select 1
        from hats h
        where h.user_id=u.id);

```
-- shows all users with no hat
select *
    from users u
    where not exists(
      select 1
        from hats h
        where h.user_id=u.id);
```

The first option doesn't plan as efficiently so it should usually be avoided:

```
-- shows all users, with a flag for whether they have a hat
select u.id, exists(
      select 1
        from hats h
        where h.user_id=u.id) as has_hat
    from users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` to find users without hat:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN hats h
  ON u.id = h.user_id
WHERE h.user_id IS NULL;
```